# Questions about std::thread class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stdthread

Considering the following class header:

```
class ThreadClass {
public:
  ThreadClass();
  ~ThreadClass();
  void operator()(int val);
  void set(int val);
  int get();
private:
  int x;
};
```

And the following implementation:

```
ThreadClass::ThreadClass(): x(0) {
  std::cout << "Constructing..." << std::endl;
}
ThreadClass::~ThreadClass() {
  std::cout << "Destructing..." << std::endl;
}
void ThreadClass::operator()(int val) {
  set(val);
  std::cout << get() << std::endl;
  set(val * 2);
  std::cout << get() << std::endl;
}
void ThreadClass::set(int val) {
  x = val;
}
int ThreadClass::get() {
  return x;
}
```

Launching the following `main`, class destructor is called several times instead of one:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::thread x = std::thread(ThreadClass(), 10);
  x.join();
  return 0;
}

>>> Constructing...
>>> Destructing...
>>> Destructing...
>>> 10
>>> 20
>>> Destructing...
```

Since my knowledge about the `std::thread` class is not so deep, I would like to ask you:

1. why this happens? Sincerely, I was expecting just a single instance of the `ThreadClass`.
2. In order to avoid unexpected behaviour, is it necessary to overload some of the class operators?

Comment: Move and copy constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking implicit constructors that you haven't defined (yet have been made for you). You can see them in action here:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class ThreadClass {
public:
  ThreadClass() {
    std::cout << "Constructing..." << std::endl;
  }
  
  ThreadClass(const ThreadClass& t) {
    std::cout << "Copy constructing..." << std::endl;
    this->x = t.x;
  }
  
//   ThreadClass(ThreadClass&& t) {
//     std::cout << "Move constructing..." << std::endl;
//     this->x = t.x;
//   }
  
  ~ThreadClass() {
    std::cout << "Destructing..." << std::endl;
  }
  
  void operator()(int val) {
      set(val);
      std::cout << get() << std::endl;
      set(val * 2);
      std::cout << get() << std::endl;
  }
  void set(int val) {
      x = val;
  }
  int get() {
      return x;
  }
private:
  int x;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::thread x = std::thread(ThreadClass(), 10);
  x.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Constructing...
>
> Copy constructing...
>
> Copy constructing...
>
> Destructing...
>
> Destructing...
>
> 10
>
> 20
>
> Destructing...

You can uncomment the move constructor if you want to see that in action as well.

To directly answer your questions:

> why this happens? Sincerely, I was expecting just a single instance of the ThreadClass.

This happens because you are passing an object around, so the additional  constructors mentioned in the post are getting called multiple times.

> In order to avoid unexpected behaviour, is it necessary to overload some of the class operators?

What do you mean by unexpected behavior? This performs exactly how C++ intends. This is well defined behavior for C++.

Comment: Since I am still not familiar with class [*special members*](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/), I was asking myself if this multiple call to destructor can create memory allocation issues but it is a *non-sense self question*: since that class instance is copied and then destructed, instances are still one when the function object is executed.